# Angular - Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typeerror

I am creating a login page using angular and typescript. When the submit button is clicked, I would like the `login` function in the controller to fire, but if the form is invalid then it just returns.

This is my first time using typescript, so every time I try to put in the if statement to check if the form is invalid it throws the error `Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined`.

Here is the html:

```
<form class="login-form" name="loginForm" ng-submit="vm.login()" novalidate>
     <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required ng-model="vm.email" ng-class="{true: 'input-error'}[submitted && loginForm.email.$invalid]"/>
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required ng-model="vm.password" ng-class="{true: 'input-error'}[submitted && loginForm.password.$invalid]"/>
     <input type="submit" id="submit" ng-click="submitted=true"/>
</form>
```

And here is the compiled javascript:

```
var LoginModule;
(function (LoginModule) {
    var LoginController = (function () {
        function LoginController() {
        }
        LoginController.prototype.login = function () {
            if(this.loginForm.$invalid) {
                return;
            }
            console.log("Login was clicked, email is " + this.email + " and password is " + this.password);
        };
        return LoginController;
    })();
    LoginModule.LoginController = LoginController;
})(LoginModule || (LoginModule = {}));
angular.module('loginModule', []).controller('LoginController', LoginModule.LoginController);
```

It looks like the common issue with this was that people were not specifying the form name, but that is not the case here. Does anyone know why I could be getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the controller alias in the form name

```
<form  name="vm.loginForm" ng-submit="vm.login()" novalidate>
```

Comment: Ahh, just started using the controllerAs syntax as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While @charlietfl's answer is correct for the OP's question, this error can also be thrown if you've missed the `ng-model` property on an input control and are using the `ui.bootstrap.showErrors` `$scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity')` method.

As [per the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/#binding-to-form-and-control-state) (my emphasis):

> .. **an input control that has the `ngModel` directive holds an instance of `NgModelController`**. Such a control instance can be published as a property of the form instance using the name attribute on the input control. The name attribute specifies the name of the property on the form instance.